# Why does Crockford use this format for writing JSON.parse function?

Tags: javascript, json, function, syntax

in this JSON.parse function:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js

Why does crockford choose to declare so many functions in his variable declarations and then separate 1 function and then return a main function at the end?

Is there benefit to writing a function like this:

pseudo syntax:

```
var json_parse = (function () {
    var x,
        y, 
        z, 
        string = function () {
             <code>
        },
        word = function () {
             <code>
        },
        white = function () {
             <code>
        },
        value;

    value = function () {
        <code>
        white();
        string();
        etc..
    };
    return function (string) {
         return something;
    }
})();
```

vs writing a function like this:

```
var parse_json = function (input) {
     var x, y, z;

     function string () {
           <code>
     }
     function word () {
           <code>
     }
     function white () {
           <code>
     }
     function value () {
         <code>
          white();
          string();
          etc..
     }

    function mainParse () {
         return something;
    }

   return mainParse(input);

};
```

Hopefully my little code examples make sense. I am new to JavaScript and I want to make sure I learn the best practices or writing large functions like this.

Comment: In the second case you create a bunch of functions every time you run `parse_json`

Comment: actually, the way you have it in the second case won't work because you return the call of a function instead of a function... if you returned a function than no more functions would be create upon use than using doug's syntax...

Comment: @dandavis In the crockford example, the outer function is immediately invoked, while the OP's is not, so they do return the same thing  -- sort of -- but like Amadan said, Crockford's only creates the functions inside the closure once.

Comment: @Semicolon: ahh, good eye. my main point was that it wasn't the "var ,,,," stuff OP asked about that caused the distinction, something the other comments+answer left unclear in my mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your variant would have to create `word`, `white`... functions each time one invokes `json_parse`. His way lets him create them once and capture them in a closure, so that they are accessible to him but not to anyone else outside his function.

Comment: ok thank you, I think I understand. And that works because he is returning the function at the end and can store the internally defined functions?

Comment: It works because IIFE creates a new scope. `(function() { ... return function() {...} })()` is the same as `function() { ... }`, but it gives you that first `...` to play with. :)

Comment: @jmancherje If you're wondering also about why he assigned most of those functions but has one as a declaration, I suspect this is to exercise careful control over what is and isn't hoisted in the IIFE scope. To what end, I'm not sure without the rest of the code. It allows the code to be more "strict" though because function declarations hoist their actual values while variable declarations hoist only the fact that the var is declared, not the value it is ultimately bound to.